# How to exclude 150*150 Image to set as a thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails

The size of the first image of each post of the feed that I am importing is 150*150. Theme always set first image as feature images so the all thumbnails are looking blurry. Is there any custom css or code so i can exclude 150*150 size image and then it will set 2nd image as feature image.
Thanks

Comment: Find the css style associated with the image and add some code to the custom css for your theme. For example, if the style is called wp_thumbnail add ".wp_thumbnail {display:none};" without the quotes. That will remove the thumbnail, but I don't know how to make it display the second image. Sorry. :)

Comment: Any css or js to set minimum required size for feature image ? all the images are external.

Comment: My understanding is that image sizes are set by the theme being used. If you want to custom size external images you might have to create a child theme and modify it as required. I'm not going to be much help here I'm afraid.